# Dynamic import vue file in typescript recursive

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

I tried to dynamically import a single file vue component in itself in typescript and got an error:

```
/Users/lilei/Desktop/designer-web/node_modules/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/lib/service.js:22
        throw error;
        ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getSymbolLinks (/Users/lilei/Desktop/designer-web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:31794:32)
    at getDeclaredTypeOfTypeAlias (/Users/lilei/Desktop/designer-web/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:36457:25)

...
```

myComp.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <my-comp v-if="someCondition"></my-comp>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
export default Vue.extend({
  data(){
    return{};
  },
  components:{
    myComp:()=>import('./myComp.vue')//Which is the name of current file, this is a official usage for dynamic loading vue component, and every thing is right in native JavaScript(not in TypeScript)
  }
})
</script>
```

I think there are some recursive tasks performed while TypeScript compiling and thrown an error. But I make sure the component won't nested itself infinity by controlling the someCondition in my logic. How to dynamic import `.vue` file recursively in TypeScript?

[vue doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components)

Comment: Use the `name` property, no need to include the component itself.

Comment: @Nit Is there a way to implement [Circular References Between Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Circular-References-Between-Components) by `name`?

Comment: As far as I know, no, but that's also very different to the question you originally asked.

Comment: @Nit Yes, use `name` property is a good way to resolve my original problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register the component to global and use it with the name.

Answer (score 0):

You are including `myComp` inside `myComp` and you end up with an infinite recursion. (you end up with a StackOverlow ;).

One way to fix this is to `name` your component and use use the given name. There is no need to import your component again. Something like this.

```
 <template>
  <div>
   <my-comp v-if="someCondition"></my-comp>
  </div>
 </template>


<script lang="ts">
 export default Vue.extend({
   name: 'my-comp',
   data(){
    return{};
   },
   components:{
   }
 })
</script>
```

And you should probably change `Vue.extend` to `Vue.component`.

Comment: I my case, I gave `myComp` component a webpack code splitting promise and when I create instance in html, It will be resolved dynamically. But TypeScript may do some static checks while compiling. Is TypeScript not full supported webpack code splitting?

Answer (score 0):

[I believe it was an issue with TypeScript, which has now been fixed.](https://github.com/TypeStrong/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/issues/197)

Try updating if you're experiencing the issue.